# When re-creating a UIViewcontroller's view, how do I force the rotation?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a view-controller that I'm re-using (for memory limitation reasons.)  So, rather than push a new UIViewController, I just set a few parameters, then force this VC to reload its view.  The code is something like this (triggered by a Notification callback):

```
- (void) reloadView: (NSNotification*) note
{
    // Save parameters for reloaded view
    UIWindow *window = (UIWindow*) self.view.superview;
    //CGAffineTransform xfrm = self.view.transform;  // Doesn't do what I want.

    // Trash this one & reload the view
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.view = nil;

    // force view reload
    if (self.view == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s ***** Why didn't self.view reload?!", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
    else
    {
        // restore params
        //self.view.transform = xfrm;  // Boo-hoo!
        [window addSubview: self.view];
    }
}
```

Everything works fine ***except*** that the app is landscape only, and the newly reloaded view is added to the Window as portrait.

I tried forcing the old view's transform onto the new view but, oddly, it gave the rotation but a goofy translation offset.

Is there a way to tell a UIViewController "do your rotation, now"...?

***EDIT:***

I added this rather silly hack:

```
    // restore params
    self.view.transform = xfrm;
    self.view.center = CGPointMake(window.bounds.size.width / 2., window.bounds.size.height / 2.);
    [window addSubview: self.view];
```

which gives the desired result, but I'm really displeased with having such a thing in my code base.  Surely there's a better way to do this?!?!

Thanks!

***EDIT:***

After some discussion with JPH, then answer turned out to be "don't do things that way."  See comments for some of the details and the redesign that took place.

Comment: have you considered reviewing the entire design? I am not sure of the context of this question, but 'forcing the rotation', 'forcing the VC to reload its view', adding subviews directly to the window... looks like a lot of hacking around..

Comment: is this the root view controller? why adding the view to the window rather than adding as a subview to a parent view controller?

Comment: Background: I have a story with a bunch of scenes.  There is a SceneViewController that displays a scene.  Same SVC for scene 1, 2, 3...  Each scene has lots of subviews with timers & animations, etc.  So I don't want to push/present a new SVC instead, I want to just reuse the one I have in place.  So I kill its view & force the reload.  So far, not TOO weird.  But the view is already on the app window, so I need to replace it there.  Ok, a little hacky.  Esp give the rotation/positioning bits, which is the question.  Your suggestion...?

Comment: Yes, root view controller.  I'm adding it to its ***EXISTING*** parent view, which happens to not be a UIView at all but, rather the Window.  While it's possible to insert a ViewController/view between the two, that doesn't really change the problem/question.

Comment: I am not understanding the need to 'kill its view', why can't the items on this view be updated without removing/readding the view?

Comment: The problem IS in adding a subview directly to the window. Only the first view added to a window is receiving the rotation events. I wrote an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in using this:

```
[window addSubview: self.view];
```

From the documentation:

> If you add an additional view controller's UIView property to UIWindow
>   (at the same level as your primary view controller) via the following:
>
> [myWindow addSubview:anotherController.view];
>
> this additional view controller will not receive rotation events and
>   will never rotate. Only the first view controller added to UIWindow
>   will rotate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html

I would much prefer a design with a root view controller and the subviews being added to the root view controller's view.

Another option is to NOT kill the view and re-add it, but rather update everything that needs to be updated in that view. I am not sure I understand why you would want to kill a view and re-add it right away.

Comment: I'm killing & re-adding it because viewDidLoad loads content based on which scene is current.  (Different content for scene1, scene2, etc.)  Basically, killing, then accessing the view is just a way to force-unload, then force viewDidLoad.  I could add an in-between view controller, that's not so hard.  Or I could put all the content into a big container-view, then ditch/recreate that (rather than the entire self.view) -- maybe that's my best solution.  Yeah, I'll experiment with that; it sounds a lot nicer.

Comment: I'm going to play with the container-view idea and, if it does what I want (seems it will), then I'll accept this answer on the basis of your "...subviews being added to the root view controller's view."  That sounds like what I really needed to do in the first place.  (FWIW, root-VC originally kicked off into a SceneViewController, it was a later design that root would also be an animated scene.  That's what led to this odd design twist.)

Comment: the viewDidLoad method is better used for one time initialization statements, those that don't change based on your model. If you need to refresh the view based on changes in your model, then you probably need a method that refreshes all UI elements. That method would be called instead of removing and adding back the view. It would also be called in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad. viewDidLoad is better suited for one time initializations.

Comment: JPH: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing: building everything into a containerView, and re-building container view when needed.  Thanks for the brain-jostle!